# CKeditor custom plugin allowedContent not working

Tags: ckeditor

I'm creating a custom plugin to allow to edit itemprop attribute.
It works great except that on reload the property gets stripped away.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I read everything I could find in the docs, including this example: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs-samples/blob/master/tutorial-abbr-acf/abbr/plugin.js#L24

If I disable ACF it works.

```js
export default CKEDITOR => {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add('itemprop', {
        init(editor) {
            editor.addCommand('itemprop', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('itempropDialog', {
                allowedContent: '*[itemprop]'
            }));

            CKEDITOR.dialog.add('itempropDialog', editor => {
                return {
                    title: 'Itemprop',
                    contents: [
                        {
                            id: 'tab-main',
                            label: 'Itemprop',
                            elements: [
                                {
                                    type: 'text',
                                    id: 'itemprop',
                                    label: 'Itemprop',
                                    setup(element) {
                                        this.setValue(element.getAttribute('itemprop'));
                                    },
                                    commit(element) {
                                        element.setAttribute('itemprop', this.getValue());
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    onShow() {
                        const selection = editor.getSelection();
                        const element = selection.getStartElement();
                        this.element = element;
                        this.setupContent(this.element);
                    },
                    onOk() {
                        this.commitContent(this.element);
                    }
                };
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: For now I was able to make it work via `extraAllowedContent('*[itemprop]')`, but I'd prefer to get the automated solution working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it might be related to this bug in CKEditor: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/678.

I've made a simple test and when I add a button to toolbar, then your code start to work. Also allowed content with `itemprop` entry start to show in CKEditor allowed filter without defining it in editor configuration. That's why the simplest solution would be adding a button to your plugin:

```
editor.ui.addButton( 'itemprop', {
  label: 'Item Prop',
  command: 'itemprop'
});
```

Entire plugin definition will be as follows:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('itemprop', {
  init(editor) {

    editor.ui.addButton( 'itemprop', {
      label: 'Item Prop',
      command: 'itemprop'
    });

    editor.addCommand('itemprop', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('itempropDialog', {
      allowedContent: '*[itemprop]'
    }));

    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('itempropDialog', editor => {
      return {
        title: 'Itemprop',
        contents: [
          {
            id: 'tab-main',
            label: 'Itemprop',
            elements: [
              {
                type: 'text',
                id: 'itemprop',
                label: 'Itemprop',
                setup(element) {
                  this.setValue(element.getAttribute('itemprop'));
                },
                commit(element) {
                  element.setAttribute('itemprop', this.getValue());
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        onShow() {
          const selection = editor.getSelection();
          const element = selection.getStartElement();
          this.element = element;
          this.setupContent(this.element);
        },
        onOk() {
          this.commitContent(this.element);
        }
      };
    });
  }
});
```

Working example here: https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/RjbOpP?editors=1010

Comment: I don’t think it has anything to do with CKEditor bug but simplify with how reporting to ACF works. When plugins has a button, you can report content to ACF in command definition: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/image/plugin.js#L38. When plugin is a combo, you need to report content in dropdown definition: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/major/plugins/font/plugin.js#L40.

Comment: If plugin has nither, there doesn't seem to be a way to add something to ACF except for `extraAllowedContent`. If you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.filter.allowedContent, null, '\t'));` you will see no `itemprop` in the output. You solution in this case is either adding a button or using `extraAllowedContent`.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm adding a command, shouldn't it work how I do it at line 9?

Comment: Later I'm executing those commands via `execCommand`: https://github.com/neos/neos-ui/blob/43ba6cb5fb3e6ffc42371d05a7598ac165067f60/packages/neos-ui-ckeditor-bindings/src/guestFrameApi.js#L139

Comment: OK, I think I got it, no native button no ACF :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, would have never figured it out myself!